# XML compression/decompression library for C# / .NET

Tags: c#, .net, xml, compression, zip

In my application the XML contains all data and it sometimes exceeds up to 5-10 MB. The file is loaded and saved many times during program execution. Although, it is fast but it seems sometimes file gets corrupted when it becomes large in size. I do not know why the file gets corrupted but in all cases the file was 5+ MB, so I am assuming the larger XML file becomes, the more susceptible it is to corruption. So, please suggest a XML file compression/decompression library

1. preferably popular compressions like zip/lzw/7zip/rar etc.
2. which must be fast. for example, it should take no more than 100 ms for compress/decompress a 10 MB file at the fastest compression level and sacrificing space.
3. easy to integrate.

I am using code:

```
XMLDocument.Load(XML_File.xml)
XMLDocument.Save(XML_File.xml)
```

So I want something like:

```
XMLDocument.Load(Library.Load(XML_File.zip))
Library.Save(XMLDocument)
```

I hope this solves my above problem. Any other alternative?

I am thinking of one more solution: if you have used winrar, you will notice that it has option to add recovery record in a .rar file so that if the file gets corrpted then it can be fixed using recovery record. Anything similar that I can use in XML files in C# programatically? like:

```
try{ 
XMLDocument.Load(Library.Load(XML_File.zip))
}
catch{ 
XMLDocument.Load(Library.Load(Library.File_Recover(XML_File.zip))) 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use a zip library from http://xceed.com/Zip_Net_Intro.html, it works well.

[I am not affiliated with them, I just purchased their product after trying a few]

I just did a search, here is a free one: http://dotnetzip.codeplex.com/

Comment: Any suggestion on the second part of the question: file recovery?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean about recovery? not familiar with that?

Comment: It is a feature in compression software "winrar" that recovers/fixes a corrupted zip file if it fails to open. Anyways, I will use the ones you mentioned. However, a recovery feature would have been an additional advantage.

Comment: You may need to look at the libraries out there to see if they support that feature, I am not sure how that works. If you are creating and manipulating your own XML file, I am surprised this is becoming corrupt? I would investigate the reason for that, compressing the file will not fix your xml file, since it will probably just compress your corrupt file?

Comment: Another option might be to investigate looking at an alternative for the data storage. Eg a database.

Comment: Can we use a database file in C# / .NET without installing a separate database? Or is there any .NET supported small database which is less than 10 MB that I can easily bundle in the software setup?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31825/discussion-between-ankit-and-mark-redman)

Comment: Sorry, didnt see the chat msh until now, have a look at http://www.sqlite.org/ for a database solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can significantly [improve the compression of XML with XWRT preprocessing](http://sourceforge.net/projects/xwrt/files/) before feeding to a standard compressor such as [zlib](http://zlib.net/) or [lzma](http://www.7-zip.org/sdk.html).